# Asgard CMS Laravel application accessed through VPN not setting cookies

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have a Asgard CMS Laravel application that I am accessing through my company's VPN network, as the server its running on, is not accessible from outside the private network.

Whenever I go to the login page, I do not see the laraval_session cookies set. The HTTP header shows the following values

```
Set-Cookie:HttpOnly;Secure
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self';
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

As you would notice, a normal Asgard CMS application running fine will have some cookies set like

```
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=<cookie value>; expires=Fri, 15-Jul-2016 10:29:57 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/

Set-Cookie:laravel_session=<cookie value>; expires=Fri, 15-Jul-2016 10:29:57 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

We see above two cookies (XSRF-TOKEN, laravel_session) are being set on an application running fine.

However in my application none of these cookies are set on the login page. Due to this token mismatch error occurs after the user tries to login, as a new token gets generated, and the one in the form is the old one.

**Also note** that additional headers (X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-Frame-Options) show up which are not there in case of normal functional laravel application.

Once we access this application outside the network, it continuously shows up this error.

Any clues on how to get the cookies show up properly, and to make my laravel application to run as normal.

Comment: Any chance you solved this problem?